# CI / CD workflow example

Tags: git, jenkins, cicd

I'm seeking a clearer understanding of git & jenkins by trying to picture the logical sequence of steps for a code change as it progresses from Dev to Prod environments. I'd appreciate if someone could let me know if my understanding is on track?

To keep the scenario simple, a company has a website consisting of only an index.html file; and that this website is hosted on 3 separate EC2 instances: 'Dev', 'Test' & 'Prod', each running Apache. The Jenkinsfile has 'build', 'test' & 'deploy' Stages. This company decides to update index.html. This is how I currently understand such a sequence of steps may 'theoretically' play out:

**a) from a git context:**

1. Developer clones / pulls / fetches (shared) dev branch of remote repo to their local IDE
2. Developer updates index.html then stages / commits this change to their local repo
3. Developer pushes change from their local repo to remote repo for dev branch
4. Developer creates pull request to seek collaborative approval for their newly-pushed dev branch change to be merged into master branch

**b) from a jenkins context:**

1. git dev branch stores all required source code / config (assume no ISOs / binaries) for dev and test EC2 instances, while git master branch stores equivalent for production environment.
2. After code changes have been made, git dev branch would store more pregressed source code / config to that of the master branch, until dev branch has been merged into master branch, which would imply that a release to production env has been deployed.
3. jenkins build stage triggers on commit of linked repo / branch and would have a step to copy latest index.html from git to EC2 'test' env then perhaps cycle Apache service and if successful, would pass pipeline execution onward to jenkins test stage.
4. jenkins test stage would run a predefined Selenium script to check localhost:80 for some known innerhtml text of index.html if successful, would pass pipeline execution onward to jenkins deploy stage.
5. jenkins deploy stage would run git merge from dev branch to master branch then if successful, would copy resulting index.html from master branch to production EC2 instance.

Thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple options, Ideally the code will be merged to master once its validated in prod .

Dev team will create a feature/dev branch to make a change ( either  from master/ci (continuous Integration/development) branch.

Make the changes in dev branch, validate the changes by deploying    the developed code into lower/dev environments.

Creates a Pull request to merge the code to CI branch Deploy the    code to test and prod environments.

If no issues found in prod , then merge the code fromCI branch to    master

Comment: Thanks @Hanuman, you've helped to reaffirm my understanding as well as helped me to realise there is a 'CI' branch! Cheers.